# Jmeter - Extract JSON field value of a SENT request

Tags: json, jmeter

I am trying to obtain data from sent JSON and use it further in another request.

My sent JSON also has dynamic variables like ${data} so the trick is that it has to execute first in order to be able to extract.

Let's say I have the following SENT JSON:

{

"field_one": ${data1},

"field_three": [more data],

"field_two": ${data2}

}

Question is: How can I extract "field_one" and "field_two" values from the sent request?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extract them, they are `${data1}` and `${data2}` so you can re-use these [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) anywhere in the script.

---

If I don't understand something obvious or you need to copy the values to another JMeter Variables, you can extract them as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which sends above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def requestBody = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
   vars.put('field_one', requestBody.field_one)
   vars.put('field_two', requestBody.field_two)
   ```
3. That's it, now you should have `${field_one}` and `${field_two}` JMeter Variables holding the values you're looking for.

In the above example `sampler` stands for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) and `vars` for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html), check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) for details on the above and other JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements.

More informaion:

- [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: Thanks again, Dmitri! Indeed, I have forgot to point out the fact that I'm trying to send the variables to another Jmeter Variable.